# "Read Aloud" not working for PDF files opened in Microsoft Edge html frame

Tags: html, accessibility, microsoft-edge, html-frames

Microsoft Edge has "Read Aloud" functionality for PDF files opened within the browser. However, this functionality does not work if the PDF file is opened within a frame in the browser.

Anybody found a solution for this?

**index.html**:

```
...
<frame name="menu" src="content.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
...
```

**content.html**:

```
<a href="http://abacus.gene.ucl.ac.uk/software/CommandLine.Unix.pdf" target="lecturesWindow"> link </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this issue, and also reproduced it with a local PDF. Apparently, Read Aloud feature is currently not supported on PDFs within `<frame>`/`<iframe>`. I suggest sending feedback to the Dev Team using `Alt+Shift+I` to request this feature. For now, you can display PDFs outside a frame if possible to use this feature.